# why using devicePixelRatio doesn't work in context

Tags: javascript, html, css

my question is about using devicePixelRatio.
Consider the following example:

```
  const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const size = 5;

  canvas.style.width = `${size}px`;
  canvas.style.height = `${size}px`;

  const scale = window.devicePixelRatio;
  canvas.width = Math.floor(size * scale);
  canvas.height = Math.floor(size * scale);
  canvas.style.backgroundColor="red";
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillRect( 3, 3, 1,1 );
```

[image]

What I would like to have is this:

[image]

my screen gives a devicePixelRatio equal to 2.
My goal is to display a point of size 1x1 in a canvas of size 5x5.
I apply what I understood, I double the size of the drawing buffer compared to the size of the display buffer.
The result is good for the point size: 1x1.
But the size of the canvas remains double. **10x10** For what ?
The explanation is certainly obvious...

---

### **re-wrote my question on May 1st, it was unclear**

I have a screen that returns a window.devicePixelRatio value equal to 2
My goal is to write code that displays a pixel in a square.
The size of the square will be 5x5 pixels.
I tried with the following code:

```js
  const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const size = 5;

  canvas.style.width = `${size}px`;
  canvas.style.height = `${size}px`;

  const scale = window.devicePixelRatio;
  canvas.width = Math.floor(size * scale);
  canvas.height = Math.floor(size * scale);
  canvas.style.backgroundColor="red";
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillRect( 3, 3, 1,1 );
```

here is the result: I took a screenshot I copied and pasted
it under Gimp,   I enlarged and added a grid
[image]

The black point, result of ctx.fillRect( 3, 3, 1,1 ) does exactly the size i wanted.
**But the red background, is a size of 10 by 10. I would like it to be 5x5**

Comment: `size = 5`,  and `scale = 2` since `devicePixelRatio = 2` so `canvas.width = Math.floor(size * scale);` and  `canvas.height = Math.floor(size * scale);` results in a **10x10** `canvas`.

Comment: See this [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio#javascript).  `.scale()` is needed.

Comment: @zer00ne Yes but i put :   canvas.style.width = `5px`;

Comment: Indeed, see previous comment and AngYC [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76144125/2813224).

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding, what OP want is to have physical pixel of 5x5px of canvas with 1x1px for the dot, here's another attempt to do it without the `.scale`:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const size = 5;
const scale = window.devicePixelRatio;

canvas.style.width = `${size}px`;
canvas.style.height = `${size}px`;
canvas.style.transform = `scale(${1 / scale })`;
canvas.style.transformOrigin = 'top left';

canvas.width = size;
canvas.height = size;
canvas.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
ctx.fillRect(3, 3, 1, 1);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" />
```

---

### Original solution

By default, the context and the canvas remains as 2 different logic, context is the drawing buffer while canvas just taking care of scaling the result of the drawing buffer to the correct size.

In order to draw in canvas for high device pixel ratio device while ensuring the canvas remains the same drawing buffer, you can make use of [`ctx.scale` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/scale), which should scale the pixel based on whichever value you pass in (such as `devicePixelRatio`):

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const size = 5;

canvas.style.width = `${size}px`;
canvas.style.height = `${size}px`;

const scale = window.devicePixelRatio;
canvas.width = Math.floor(size * scale);
canvas.height = Math.floor(size * scale);
canvas.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
ctx.scale(scale, scale);
ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
ctx.fillRect(3, 3, 1, 1);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" />
```

Comment: but the result (on my devicePixelRation 2 screen) is a 10x10 canvas with a 2x2 dot.
I would like a 1x1 pixel in a 5x5 canvas

Comment: Hi @oceanGermanique, can I check what you want is a 2.5x2.5px (logical pixel) on your device with pixel ratio of 2? So the physical pixel would be 5x5px. In that case, you should not scale the context but the canvas instead

Comment: I rewrote my question, maybe it wasn't clear.

Comment: Hi @oceanGermanique, I have modified my solution to always render a `5x5px` of canvas with `1x1px` of physical pixel for the black dot, it should work fine now for your screenshot. Screenshot on a 1920x1080 screen with devicePixelRatio of `2` actually gives you the screenshot size of 3840x2160, which explain why the red box is `10x10px`.